# SQL query filter a row with a specific combination only

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, where-clause

I am trying to query a table in which I have a specific condition, I do not want to query rows where Reference Category is Production and Issue is Sold.

[image]

In the above table, I want row 1,2& 4 only - How do I make such a query. If i do WHERE ReferenceCategory = 'Production line' AND Issue = 'Sold', it takes away row 4 as well.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f54f5b/1

Answer (score 5):

> I do not want to query rows where Reference Category is Production and [Issue is] Sold

You could simply phrase the conditions as follows:

```
WHERE NOT (ReferenceCategory = 'Production line ' AND Issue = 'Sold')
```

In your **[demo on DB Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f54f5b/8/0)**, this returns records 1, 2, 4.

Answer (score -2):

Answered by @GMB:

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionTable
WHERE NOT (ReferenceCategory = 'Production line' AND Issue = 'Sold')
```

For AX/D365 X++ user, the use of logical expression NOT(A and B) is not allowed in a X++ query range, therefore, transforming NOT(A and B) to its equivalent expression according to **De'Morgans Law**:

---

NOT(A and B) = (NOT A) OR (NOT B)

---

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionTable
WHERE ReferenceCategory <> 'Production line' OR Issue <> 'Sold'**
```

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "simple SQL"? `NOT (A AND B)` is extremely simple, valid SQL.

Comment: `NOT` isn't properly a function. It's a logical operator.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Thank you for your comment - There is a language called X++ and there is an object called Query. In a query, when you specify query conditions (these are called ranges), and NOT (A and B) logical expression is not allowed, therefore I had to rely on it equivalent logical expression.

Comment: @shawnt00 I am sorry, you got it right, I am going to correct this and eventually I will be going to delete my answer, as it will become ambiguous for SQL users. My answer is in leiu of X++ where NOT(A and B) is not allowed. Please see my comments above for DaleBurrell.

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR you need to specify that sort of detail as part of the question.